# Drawing a torus not bounding a solid torus

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am trying to make a "pretty" picture of a torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which does not bound a solid torus.  The standard way of constructing such a thing is to first take a non-trivial torus knot:

```
f[t_, s_] := {(2 + Cos[s]) Cos[t], (2 + Cos[s]) Sin[t], Sin[s]} - 
             {2,0, 0}
 ParametricPlot3D[f[t, 3 t/2], {t, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

This is the trefoil knot (the minus $\lbrace2,0,0\rbrace$ will be explained shortly).  We then take a tubular neighborhood around this knot:

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
df[t_] := Evaluate[D[f[t, 3 t/2], t]]
v1[t_] := CrossProduct[df[t], {0, 1, 0}] // Normalize
v2[t_] := CrossProduct[df[t], v1[t]] // Normalize
ParametricPlot3D[
f[t, 3 t/2] + Cos[\[Theta]] v1[t] + Sin[\[Theta]] v2[t],
{t, 0,4 Pi}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None]
```

(I checked beforehand that the derivative is never in the $\lbrace0,1,0\rbrace$ direction.)

Now I define the composition of a stereographic projection to $S^3$, and one back to $\mathbb{R}^3$. The key is that the latter map can be from *any* point, so I simply pick one that lies on my knot! [This is why I subtracted $\lbrace2,0,0\rbrace$ before: it ensures the origin lies on the knot, and gives this composition a very easy form.]

```
s3Proj[v_]:=v/(Norm[v]^2)
ParametricPlot3D[s3Proj[
f[t, 3 t/2] + Cos[\[Theta]] v1[t] + Sin[\[Theta]] v2[t]],
{t, 0,4 Pi}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None]
```

The problem is (I don't know how to include the picture) that Mathematica is not drawing this torus the way I want.  By looking at the "general shape", I know it is the right torus, but for some reason Mathematica is "flaying" the ends of this torus out. I think the problem is due to the fact that any such torus has to travel "inside" itself (basically tracing the knot and then "exiting" itself again), and Mathematica gets confused in how to draw that.

Is there some way to "clean up" this plot? Or maybe someone knows another way to draw an attractive version of this torus?

[My browser is acting up and I cannot tag this question; please feel free to tag it for me.]

Comment: Is the last `ParametricPlot3D` command correct? (`s3Proj` is never used)

Comment: @ssch: Oh no it isn't, thank you!

Comment: Just a related note: You can get different kinds of knots using `KnotData`. You can get a trefoil with `KnotData["Trefoil"]` and its parametric curve with `KnotData["Trefoil", "SpaceCurve"]`

Comment: I can't say I'm particularly au fait with stereographic projections, so I'm not sure what you are expecting.  But the surface of your knot goes through the origin, so dividing by the norm is going to make things fly off to infinity.

Comment: Your knot surface has self-intersections, which make it look very confusing when you turn it inside out. You could try making it less thick. Beyond that, I'm with wxffles here: it would really help if you could explain more clearly what you mean by "drawing this torus the way I want". Perhaps with some sort of a sketch of the shape you expect to see? Anyway, I played around with it and the best I could get is http://i.stack.imgur.com/sPXs0.png

Comment: @wxffles: The knot goes through the origin, but the surface does not.  THe idea is to make a point on the *interior* of the surface "equal to infinity".

Comment: @RahulNarain: Here is a partcularly nice picture of such a torus: http://themathingpot.wordpress.com/category/low-dimensional-topology/ . This is the same torus Mathematica is drawing, except it is "flaying" the sides out for some reason.  Again, you are right: the self-intersections are making it hard on Mathematica.

Comment: But your surface does go through the origin! The knot goes through $(1,0,0)$ instead.

Comment: @RahulNarain: You are absolutely right! It should be $\{1,0,0\}$, not $\{2,0,0\}$

Comment: @RahulNarain: And now I feel stupid...the picture is coming out much nicer now.  I am going to increase MaxRecursion to get a smoother plot, but I will post a picture when Mathematica finishes.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

First off, no need to make a curve a function of two variables:

```
f[t_] := With[{s = 3 t/2}, {(2 + Cos[s]) Cos[t], (2 + Cos[s]) Sin[t], 
    Sin[s]} - {2, 0, 0}]
ParametricPlot3D[f[t], {t, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

[image]

Then you can just use `f'[t]` as a convenient syntax for `D[f[t],t]`. Your chosen torus has self-intersections, so I'll define the torus with a lower thickness. Also, it's more natural to take the cross product with the $z$-axis. Using `Evaluate` makes the plot faster, allowing us to bump up the `MaxRecursion` in turn.

```
v1[t_] := Cross[f'[t], {0, 0, 1}] // Normalize
v2[t_] := Cross[f'[t], v1[t]] // Normalize
g[t_, \[Theta]_] := 
 f[t] + (Cos[\[Theta]] v1[t] + Sin[\[Theta]] v2[t])/2
ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate@g[t, \[Theta]], {t, 0, 4 Pi}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Mesh -> None, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]

But your real problem is that you are performing inversion with respect to a point that's not on the central knot, as you claim, but on the surface of the torus instead. Why not just explicitly choose the point using `f` which we already have?

```
s3Proj[v_] := v/Norm[v]^2
ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate@s3Proj[g[t, \[Theta]] - f[0]], {t, 0, 4 Pi}, {\[Theta], 0, 
  2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 6, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]
```

[image]

Actually, using `f[2 Pi/3]` instead of `f[0]` gives a more attractive surface. And there you go: a torus with a knot in its hole.

[image]

Comment: You are awesome!  Can I ask a tangential question, as I am now completely satisfied with this answer: why does Evaluate make things faster?

Comment: [From the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html): "`Plot` has attribute `HoldAll` and evaluates $f$ only after assigning specific numerical values to $x$.
In some cases, it may be more efficient to use `Evaluate` to evaluate $f$ symbolically before specific numerical values are assigned to $x$." The same is true of `ParametricPlot3D` and most other plotting functions.